# Jest Unit test for component using nextjs and next-intl

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js, internationalization

I'm trying to create a unit test for my nextjs-component using next-intl.

My component:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";

export default function Home() {
  const t = useTranslations("HomePage");

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My title goes here</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <h1>{t("welcome")}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

// Get localized messages
export function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
  return {
    props: {
      messages: require(`locales/${locale}.json`),
    },
  };
}
```

How can one create a unit test in lines of:

```
 import Home from '../pages/index'
 
 describe('Home', () => {
   it('renders a heading', () => {
     render(<Home />)
 
     const heading = screen.getByRole('heading', {level: 1})
 
     expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument()
   })
 })
```

Have tried to mock next-intl without any luck. Also tried to wrap Home in a `<NextIntlProvider messages={localization}>` where localization is a json containing localized strings, but it still states locale is null. If anyone could help me write a simple unit test or an example of a unit test for a component using `next-intl`, it would be much appreciated.

Links to docs:
i18n Next: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing
next-intl: https://formatjs.io/docs/getting-started/installation/

---

**UPDATE**: now working :)

I managed to run my test with the following setup:

```
 import React from 'react'
 import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
 import { NextIntlProvider } from "next-intl";
 import Home from '../pages/index'
 
 describe('Home Component', () => {
    const useRouter = jest.spyOn(require('next/router'), 'useRouter')
    const locale = 'no-NB';
    const messages = require(`../locales/${locale}.json`);

    useRouter.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
        query: { locale: locale },
    }))

    it('renders a heading', () => {
        render(
            <NextIntlProvider messages={messages} locale={locale}>
                <Home />
            </NextIntlProvider>
        )
 
        const heading = screen.getByRole('heading', {level: 1})
        expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument()
   })
 })
```

Comment: Great to hear you got it working eventually! There's a small section in the FAQs about jest: https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/faq#can-next-intl-be-used-in-environments-like-jest-and-storybook. It links to a working example: https://github.com/amannn/next-intl/blob/main/packages/example-advanced/src/components/Navigation.spec.tsx. If you think that something could be improved in the documentation please let me know!